# Looping through objects

Tags: php, oop, object

Suppose you have this array with objects:

```
array
0 => 
object(User\Entity\User)[297]
  public 'id' => int 1
  private 'first_name' => string 'Peter' (length=5)
  private 'last_name' => string 'Johnson' (length=7)
  private 'initials' => string 'J.J.' (length=4)
  private 'email' => string 'test@gmail.com' (length=21)
 1 => 
object(User\Entity\User)[296]
  public 'id' => int 2 
  private 'first_name' => string 'Edith' (length=8)
  private 'last_name' => string 'Peters' (length=7)
  private 'initials' => string 'R.J.' (length=4)
  private 'email' => string 'edit@gmail.com' (length=26)
```

Now i want to put them in a table. But since i want to make it universal i try to do it on an abstract way.

I have a $aColnames array in the function below in to be able to only show the get the values of the fields i want to see in the table.

This is the method i am trying to build:

```
private function generateTable()
{

    foreach($this->aData as $aData){
      $this->sTable.= '<tr>';
      foreach($this->aColnames as $sColname){
          $this->sTable.= '<td>';
/****What code goes here ****/
              $this->sTable.= '</td>';
      }
          $this->sTable.= '</tr>';
        }
    }
```

The question is no how do i get the values from the objects? Do i need to instantiate the objects each time? Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: You probably want to make your properties public, or you won't be able to access them in your function.

Comment: If objects aren't instantiated, they won't exist, so I have problems to understand the part of the question that asks about instantiating.

Comment: Where does `generateTable()` live?  Is it in a base class (e.g., `\User\Entity`), or is it implemented in an entirely separate class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to instantiate the objects again. They are instantiated when you placed them in the array in the first place!

You will however need to either declare these variables public, so that they may be accessed, or have some sort of getter functions.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to make the properties public.  You could provide a `__get($property)` implementation that would allow the retrieval of the properties value without giving calling code the ability to change the values of those properties.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry: Yes that is also a possibility. Though I don't want to confuse this (probably) new php programmer and induce some more complexities over his code/mind/whatever.